# File.open, open and IO.foreach in Ruby, what is the difference?

Tags: ruby, file-io

All of the following API do the same thing: open a file and call a block for each line. Is there any preference we should use one than another?

```
File.open("file").each_line {|line| puts line}
open("file").each_line {|line| puts line}   
IO.foreach("file") {|line | puts line}
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There are important differences beetween those 3 choices.

## `File.open("file").each_line { |line| puts line }`

- `File.open` opens a local file and returns a file object
- the file stays open until you call `IO#close` on it

## `open("file").each_line { |line| puts line }`

`Kernel.open` looks at the string to decide what to do with it.

```
open(".irbrc").class # => File
open("http://google.com/").class # => StringIO
File.open("http://google.com/") # => Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - http://google.com/
```

In the second case the `StringIO` object returned by `Kernel#open` actually holds the content of http://google.com/. If `Kernel#open` returns a `File` object, it stays open untill you call `IO#close` on it.

## `IO.foreach("file") { |line| puts line }`

- `IO.foreach` opens a file, calls the given block for each line it reads, and closes the file afterwards.
- You don't have to worry about closing the file.

## `File.read("file").each { |line| puts line }`

You didn't mention this choice, but this is the one I would use in most cases.

- `File.read` reads a file completely and returns it as a string.
- You don't have to worry about closing the file.
- In comparison to `IO.foreach` this makes it clear, that you are dealing with a file.
- The memory complexity for this is O(n). If you know you are dealing with a small file, this is no drawback. But if it can be a big file and you know your memory complexity can be smaller than O(n), don't use this choice.

It fails in this situation:

```
 s= File.read("/dev/zero") # => never terminates
 s.each …
```

## ri

ri is a tool which shows you the ruby documentation. You use it like this on your shell.

```
ri File.open
ri open
ri IO.foreach
ri File#each_line
```

With this you can find almost everything I wrote here and much more.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ri.  It could be more friendly, though.  "ri File.open" doesn't find anything for me.  Trying to find "open" I eventually find Kernel#orig_open and then try looking up "Kernel#open" only to be told there are multiple matches without any apparent way to just give me the docs for exactly Kernel#open instead of searching for Kernel#open*.

Comment: If you pass a block to `File.open` it will be closed automatically when the block terminates, no need to call `IO#close`

Comment: File is a subclass of IO, so you can use File.foreach instead of IO.foreach if you want to make it more self-documenting that you are working with a file.  Be aware that File.read().each is loading the entire file into memory.  If you're working with large files this may not be advisable.  I would stick with File.foreach.

Comment: Thank you for the RI tip. That's something so useful.

Comment: `File.read("file").each { |line| puts line }` doesn't seem to work in all cases as it cannot process it line-by-line. My failing example is a plain text file with `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: If you need access to the line numbers of the file (or index), you can chain `with_index` onto `File.foreach`, like so: `File.foreach("file").with_index { |line, index| row = index + 1 }`

Comment: I needed to run `rvm docs generate` . (I know, I´m new to ruby)

Comment: So when i have to deal with large files and want to take care of memory I always should use `IO.foreach (File.foreach)`. That i know, but I always thought that `File.open().each_line` was a alias for `IO.foreach`. That is wrong right? I couldn't find out clearly in relation of memory usage.